# MongoDB error trying to delete array item

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, mongodb, post

I am trying to delete an item from an array in a MongoDB model.
Here is my Country model:

```
const CountrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    holidays: 
        [
            {
                day: {type: Number, required: true},
                month: {type: Number, required: true},
                description: { type: String, required: true }
            },
        ],
    states: { type: [String], required: true }
});
```

I already have on database a few countries and I have an endpoint which deletes a holiday from the Country. I have the country name from the request params and giving the holiday information from POST. Like that:

```
{
    "day": 10,
    "month": 4,
    "description": "Random party"
}
```

So my function deleteHoliday it's like this:

```
function deleteHoliday(req, res) {
    var country_name = req.params.country_name;
    var n_description = new Country(req.body.description);
    let query = Country.update({ 'name': country_name }, { '$pull': { holidays: { description: n_description }}})

    query.exec( (err, holidays) =>{
        //Check if no errors and send json back
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.status(200).json({message:"Holiday removed successfully"});
    })
}
```

I'm not really sure on how to execute the query but, before the query is executed, I get the next error:

> ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got Random party.

I just want to delete the holiday item with the description given. In this case Random party.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I made a mistake, I was passing an object type Country instead of the description.

```
var n_description = new Country(req.body.description);

should be

var n_description = req.body.description;
```

Alredy solved it!

Answer (score 0):

mistake is here,

```
var n_description = new Country(req.body.description);
```

a simple string is expected, change this accordingly.